# What does this strange icon next to Roblox usernames mean?

Tags: roblox

I was in a game when I found somebody with this near their user, what does it mean?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the symbol on roblox servers, too.You can look in the description of the server you are playing on and try to get your answer.I do have an answer for what you’re looking for actually.In most of the descriptions of the servers I have been to and have this symbol next to a player’s name, It says that it means the player is doing something like trading with another player or checking out game offers.I don’t know if this answer will help, but it’s all I got.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing remotely close to this in roblox's UI files. My only guesses are either your UI files have corrupted somehow, or it's an addition to the specific game you were playing.