# What does this warning symbol next to player names in Roblox mean?

Tags: roblox

So I found this warning symbol looking thing next to these two names and was wondering what this meant. Can anyone help me?

[image: A list of player names, two showing a "warning" symbol]

Comment: im guessing this is game-specific bc i dont play roblox but i remember another question had the same thing just with a different icon and it turned out to be game-specific

Comment: i cant verify this answer is accurate, but may be some help: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/377603/258509

Comment: Can you tell us which Roblox game this was in? It might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked through the roblox UI asset files - this doesn't exist in them. The error logo is inside a tilted square:

[image: The error icon, at 3x scale]

It's been added by whichever game you were playing at the time.

Answer (score -1):

I thought is was a block symbol but it's not, I think it's a warning to players who said some bad words or hackers.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This looks like a speculation and not a real answer